# How to change two columns of a long table to a wide table in R?

Tags: r

I want to make a wide table with the data from a long table which only has two columns, I´ve tried in many ways but I couldn't do it. What funtion do I need to use?

Long table:

| Cepas | Valor |
| --- | --- |
| B1 | 5.3 |
| B1 | 4.25 |
| B1 | 2.2 |
| B1 | 2.5 |
| B2 | 3.15 |
| B2 | 2.5 |
| B2 | 5.7 |

Wide table (expected output):

| B1 | B2 | B3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5.3 | 3.15 | 17.8 |
| 4.25 | 2.5 | 2.6 |
| 2.2 | 5.7 | 3.1 |
| 2.5 | 2.5 | 31.1 |

Comment: please post the data as texts not as images/links

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57013551/646761

Comment: If you only have these two columns, you can just do `unstack(df[2:1])`

Comment: Welcome to SO, Carlos Gonzalez! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: This question is a duplicate of several others, so it'll be closed shortly. The reason it'll be closed has nothing to do with the quality of your question, the act of closing is meant to allow the answers in the _other_ links to percolate to the top of searches. Hope you stick around StackOverflow!